# MySQL privileges table, access from PHP for use in another database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, user-permissions

I'm building a PHP app tied to a MySQL-based database called "cc".  For looking up user (or user group) privileges on my database, is it necessary for the app to connect to the "mysql" database just to access its User and DB tables, or should I replicate the structure of these tables in my database so the app only needs to connect to it?

Or should the app use a single db-admin user for SQL from all app users and control their privileges strictly through code?  This would avoid needing to look up privileges for each user (or each type of user), but violates the principle of keeping DB access to the minimum needed by the user.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Perhaps you should explain your design a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The most common pattern is that your application connects to the database with a MySQL-user, and that user has sufficient privileges to perform all data manipulation needed.

Your application then manage the users using the application. You can write this code yourself, or use a framework like [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/Security)

Comment: I think I was making things too complicated.  Here's what I think might work -- feedback welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was making things too complicated.  Here's what I think might work -- feedback welcome.  1. App user submits user ID and pwd. (This app is for internal staff, so only the app admin creates users.)  2. App connects to DB through an authentication connection with access only to a Users table to determine the user's perms level.  3. App reconnects to DB as predefined DB-user with the appropriate perms.  Does this make sense?